# comobobox selected item index not changing

Tags: vb.net, indexing, combobox

i created a simple forme with three combobox1,2,3. the combobox1 should return the combobox3 to index -1, but after selecting an item for combobox3, the changing in combobox1 dont change the combobox3 to the index -1, thank you.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i = 0 To 3
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString)
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(i.ToString)
        ComboBox3.Items.Add(i.ToString)
    Next
    ComboBox2.Enabled = False
    ComboBox3.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex() = -1
    ComboBox3.SelectedIndex() = -1
    ComboBox2.Enabled() = True
    ComboBox3.Enabled() = False
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox3.Enabled() = True
    ComboBox3.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox3.Items.Add("0")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: also removing the line "ComboBox3.Items.Clear()" will make the selected item change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it does change the `Selectedindex` to -1.  If you'd debugged properly and actually looked at the `SelectedIndex`, you'd have seen that that was the case.  You made an assumption based on the UI, but that's just showing the `Text`.  It's not clearing the `Text` of the control even though it's resetting the `SelectedIndex` to -1.  That's a bit odd but it is what it is.

You can either clear the `Text` too or do what you probably should have done in the first place and set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`.  If you do that then the control will never display text except for the `SelectedItem`, which is what you want a `ComboBox` to do in most cases anyway.  Unless you specifically want the user to be able to type in arbitrary text, don't leave the `DropDownStyle` set to the default `DropDown`.

EDIT:

Actually, I just tried this code and it worked fine, even with each `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDown`:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i = 0 To 3
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString)
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(i.ToString)
        ComboBox3.Items.Add(i.ToString)
    Next
    ComboBox2.Enabled = False
    ComboBox3.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1
    ComboBox2.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1
    ComboBox3.Enabled = (ComboBox2.SelectedIndex <> -1)
End Sub
```

There's not really any reason to be referring to `ComboBox3` in the event handler for `ComboBox1` anyway.

Comment: ok,thank you, now i replaced the line by     combobox3.text =""

Comment: sorry i could not feedback your question , i have not 15 reputaion yet

Comment: yes, it is not necessary to  change the itemindex in the event handler for ComboBox1, it works good, thank you so much

Comment: @jmcilhinney So glad you answered this. But here's something that I can't seem to find why it works if you take the original code and reverse the two selectedindex lines in the combobox1_selectedindexchanged method. If you set Combobox3 before Combobox2 it seems to work as the OP expected. Any insights? Just been trying to see why and am apparently missing something in the order the code executes.

Comment: @IngA Please accept jmcilhinney 's answer as an answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark to the left of the answer. This will help future readers and get you a couple of points.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , i fond another solution in another question, the handler of combobox index changing cause the code in index change to run when the selected index change, the solution was to stop the handler and start it again , by addhandler and removehandler

Comment: RemoveHandler comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged                           'for example